# Change the site look based on user's list item property

Tags: sharepoint, branding

We have a list containing the `ADUsername` and `Boolean field (Yes/No)` columns. Based on the logged in user we are fetching this list item and corresponding value for yes/no field.

Now we want to change the look of the SharePoint site based on this value.

> - Yes=Blue suitebar and top bar.
> - No=Green suitebar and top bar.

Possible solutions we have envisioned:

> - Composed looks (we have worked on this but not sure if they can be changed on run time)
> - Master page (creating master page with hardcoded blue/green color, but not sure if it is possible to call master page at runtime)

I believe both above methods will fail as there will be multiple users accessing the site at same time and changing the master page/composed look at run time is not feasible.

The 3rd method we were thinking of is to use Javascript on the Master Page using client object model to detect the list item (yes/no) value and change the CSS colors/file dynamically.

Let me know your views on this approach or other possible solution. Thanks.